# 5000mg Taurine bad?

Tags: food, supplements

I just got my new Whey/Caseine/Egg protein supplement which also contains 5000 mg Taurine per 100gram.

I am planning to take this supplement on a daily basis (as breakfast with some milk and cereals)

I know energy drinks contains lower volumes (like 1000-2000mg). Is Taurine any bad for your health? I can only find positive features ;) (like it's good for your heart, eyes, skin, muscles, etc)

Comment: Off topic per new [FAQ]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A 2003 study by the European Food Safety Authority found no adverse effects for up to 1,000 mg of taurine per kilogram of body weight per day. (http://www.efsa.europa.eu/EFSA/efsa_locale-1178620753812_1211902328128.htm)

Related question: https://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/612/35

Edit: I'm assuming you weight more than 5kg (11 lbs).

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) I am not near 5kg ;)